# The code in my Java project isn't finding the imports from a referenced library

Tags: java, weka

I'm writing a project that uses two classes generated by a different program. I copied the code and pasted it into two empty Java classes. These classes import various classes from the weka.jar file I have added to the project's build path, but all the import lines come up with "Import X cannot be resolved" errors (X being the imported class).

I have two versions of the project:

- one where weka.jar is in a "lib" folder (at the same level as the "src" folder containing the two classes) which I right-clicked on in the package navigator of eclipse and selected Build Path->Add to build path
- the other where I right-clicked on the project and selected Build Path->Add External Archives, and navigated to and selected the weka.jar file (in its original location, the program files of the Weka software) as prompted.

I've done this before in the past with success, and I'm not sure why it's not working now?

Comment: Could this be an Eclipse specific problem? Maybe add the tag? I've also had similar issues but on Netbeans and the setting there is called 'classpath' (never found a reliable fix other than using the builtin library tool)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've had a look at the classpath variable and added the jar file to it since it wasn't there but this did not fix the problem.I went through the Windows dropdown to Preferences where I then followed Java->Build Path->Classpath Variables

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question because I found the answer: my jar file was in my User folder (C:\Users[myname]) which Windows apparently limits access to. I moved it into the C drive and the imports worked :)

I still get the error

> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make
> protected final java.lang.Class
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
> throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does
> not "opens java.lang" to module weka

at multiple places in

> java.base/java.lang.reflect
> weka/weka.core.WekaPackageClassLoaderManager
> weka/weka.core.ResourceUtils
> weka/weka.classifiers.trees.J48

And once in my own code.

I also have multiple warnings (probably the reason for the errors), but my program runs as it should (bar the error message output).